# SSH server using NodeJs which accepts forwarded Port

Tags: node.js, ssh, jsch, portforwarding, openssh

I have a client SSH sever written in Java using JSCH lib which is forwarding Port from client to ssh server like This[JSCH client](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingR.java.html)  , Now I want a ssh server which will accept the Port forwarded from client in NODEJS!(I have read documentation on SSH2 and SSH modules but there is nothing regarding server which accepts the port), I am able to create a server(using [ssh2 module Nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2)) and client also connecting but not accepting the forwarded Port.Below is the Code for server.

```
    var webSocketPort=20;
var fs = require('fs'),
crypto = require('crypto'),
inspect = require('util').inspect;
var buffersEqual = require('buffer-equal-constant-time'),
ssh2 = require('ssh2'),
utils = ssh2.utils;

var pubKey = utils.genPublicKey(utils.parseKey(fs.readFileSync('C:\\Program         Files\\OpenSSH\\etc\\ssh_host_rsa_key.pub')));

new ssh2.Server({
hostKeys: [fs.readFileSync('C:\\Program   Files\\OpenSSH\\etc\\ssh_host_rsa_key')]
 }, function(client) {
console.log('Client connected!',client);
client.on('authentication', function(ctx) {
if (ctx.method === 'password'
    || ctx.username === '418374'
    || ctx.password === 'hiandroid8@3') {
  ctx.accept();
  console.log("inside userpwd")
}
else if (ctx.method === 'publickey'
         && ctx.key.algo === pubKey.fulltype
         && buffersEqual(ctx.key.data, pubKey.public)) {
    console.log("inside publicKey")
  if (ctx.signature) {
      console.log("inside signature")
    var verifier = crypto.createVerify(ctx.sigAlgo);
    verifier.update(ctx.blob);
    if (verifier.verify(pubKey.publicOrig, ctx.signature))
      ctx.accept();
    else
      ctx.reject();
  } else {
      console.log("inside nthing")
    // if no signature present, that means the client is just checking 
    // the validity of the given public key 
    ctx.accept();
  }
} else
  ctx.reject();
  }).on('ready', function() {
 console.log('Client authenticated!');
 client.on('session', function(accept, reject) {
    console.log('Client Sssio!');
   var session = accept();
  session.once('exec', function(accept, reject, info) {
    console.log('Client wants to execute: ' + inspect(info.command));
    var stream = accept();
    stream.stderr.write('Oh no, the dreaded errors!\n');
    stream.write('Just kidding about the errors!\n');
    stream.exit(0);
    stream.end();
  });
});
client.on('request', function(accept, reject, name,info,a) {
    console.log('accept',accept)
    console.log('reject',reject)
    console.log('info',info)
    console.log('name',name)
    if(name==="tcpip-forward"){
        //info.bindAddr='localhost';
    }
    console.log('infoafgter',info)
  var session = accept();
    console.log('tcpIp');
  })
   function reExec(i) {
    if (i === 3)
     return;
       client.forwardOut('0.0.0.0', 3000, 'localhost', 8080, function(err,          stream) {
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        stream.end();
      reExec(++i);
    });
  }
  reExec(0);
  }).on('error',function(e){
  console.log("error occcured",e)
  }).on('end', function() {
   console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
 }).listen(webSocketPort, '0.0.0.0', function() {
console.log('Listening on port ' + webSocketPort);
});
```

Comment: You should show code that you've already tried.

Comment: Do you really need to write your own ssh server? OpenSSH can be configured to connect clients to a custom application.

Comment: @mscdex Adding server code.

Comment: @Kenster Server because,I want total control for manupulating traffic and authentication of request coming to server

Comment: Seems like you have elixir of life. Don't waste your life to wheel reinventing. If you want custom authentication - just implement pam module for this. [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/792804/use-custom-ssh-authentication-mechanism-openssh)

Comment: @SRK Your `request` event handler looks fine. Did you verify that it gets called? If so, all you need to do is call `client.forwardOut()` to alert the client of an incoming connection on the address/port they requested.

Comment: @mscdex Yes request getting called.I am able to start the ssh server and its showing the client connected when I am connecting via JSCH java client but port I am not able to forward. Same client working with OpenSSH server.

Comment: As I mentioned, you will have to handle the connecting of sockets yourself. This means creating a `net.Server` for the ssh connection and listening on the requested port. When a connection comes in, call `client.forwardOut()`. If/when the client accepts, then pipe the socket to the resulting stream and back again.

Comment: I already tried it but its throwing error as `{ [Error: (SSH) Channel open failure: open failed] reason: 'ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED', lang: '' }'`
 thats mean I have allow **AllowTcpForwarding no** which I am not finding how to do it

Comment: @mscdex Please check the code , am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Answer here :

[Create a Node SSH2 Server with ability to treat Remote Forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372083/create-a-node-ssh2-server-with-ability-to-treat-remote-forwarding/50427158#50427158)

```
let fs = require('fs'),
  inspect = require('util').inspect,
  ssh2 = require('ssh2'),
  net = require('net');

new ssh2.Server({
  hostKeys: [fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key')]
}, client => {
  console.log('Client connected!');
  client
    .on('authentication', ctx => {
      if (
        ctx.method === 'password'
        && ctx.username === 'foo'
        && ctx.password === 'bar'
      ) {
        ctx.accept();
      } else {
        ctx.reject();
      }
    })
    .on('ready', () => {
      console.log('Client authenticated!');
      client
        .on('session', (accept, reject) => {
          let session = accept();
          session.on('shell', function(accept, reject) {
            let stream = accept();
          });
        })
        .on('request', (accept, reject, name, info) => {
          if (name === 'tcpip-forward') {
            accept();
            net.createServer(function(socket) {
              socket.setEncoding('utf8');
              client.forwardOut(
                info.bindAddr, info.bindPort,
                socket.remoteAddress, socket.remotePort,
                (err, upstream) => {
                  if (err) {
                    socket.end();
                    return console.error('not working: ' + err);
                  }
                  upstream.pipe(socket).pipe(upstream);
                });
            }).listen(info.bindPort);
          } else {
            reject();
          }
        });
    });
}).listen(21, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + this.address().port);
});
```